# Can i connect new IBOutlet to a child's class?

Tags: ios, xcode

I have 2 TableViewCells. Both are exactly alike but the second one hides a label. Is there a way to inherit from the first one and give it a special IBOutlet to the second one? or must I give the reference to the parent class?

Comment: What is the need for "inherit" in this situation?

Comment: use the same cell in your TB, in case your are in your second, hide what you need.

Comment: I wanna know if it is possible since i may have to later give different kind of behaviour to each one and i don't want to keep creating if statements in each method.

Comment: Look at this question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/29284655/3050403